# Get java.lang.NumberFormatException for DriverManager.getConnection

Tags: java, mysql, scala, numberformatexception

I am writing an application in Scala. I am trying to connect to mysql database. To do that I am using `java.sql.DriverManager`. But I am getting a **NumberFormatException**

Here is my code.

```
val user = "root"
val password = "rootpassword"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://root:rootpassword@localhost:3306/database_name";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
val connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
```

Here is the error I am getting.

> [error] application - Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "firstlook@localhost:3306"'.

Comment: Dont use Class.forName. , instead of it use  DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

Comment: Remove "root:rootpassword@" from the url

Comment: Let me try this. I will get back in a moment. Thanks.

Comment: It has worked. Thank you very very much. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the user and password from the url:

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name";
```

Comment: Well then how do you authenticate? I'm getting `CJException Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck athentication will be done by  `DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)`

Comment: I don't have access to that, the library I'm using expects a URI.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck create a new Question hier on stackoverflow with code and so on. Not comment and old answer